# Combination and counting problem

Tags: combinatorics

I am confused by the following question, 
There are 15 students, 8boys and 7 girls, how many different combination to choose 6 students in which at least 2boys and 2 girls are chosen.

My way: $\binom{8}{2}\binom{7}{2}\binom{11}{2} = 32,340$

The solution: $\binom{8}{2}\binom{7}{4}+\binom{8}{3}\binom{7}{3}+\binom{8}{4}\binom{7}{2}= 4,410$

My way of thinking is choose 2 from boys and choose 2 from girls, and choose two from the remaining (15-4). However, the answer is by calculating the sample space (2boys4girls, 3boys3girls, 4boys2girls), and I don't know why my way of thinking is incorrect.

Comment: Every possibility is counted more than once by your method.

Comment: Your way of counting double counts quite a bit.  For example, if I name some of the guys Abe, Ben, Chad, and Dan, then your first sampling may choose Abe and Ben and the last sampling can choose Chad and Dan, however you count this as different from first choosing Abe and Chad then finally Ben  and Dan.

Comment: Mathematically, the numbers "on top" should sum up to $15$ and the numbers "on bottom" should sum up to $6$. As you can see, in your calculation, the numbers "on top" sum up to $26$.

Comment: This is an error of overcounting - and sadly, this is an error all combinatorialists go through at first.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to exclude the unwanted combinations if the total number of students to be chosen is large.

$$\binom {15}6-\binom70\binom86-\binom 71\binom 85-\binom80\binom76-\binom81\binom75=4140\quad\blacksquare$$

This is not the case here though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is essentially the same as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993074/ways-to-choose-10-questions-from-a-13-divided-into-two-sets): the reason your method gives the wrong answer is that it double-counts some choices. For example, choosing $\{B_1, B_2\}$ as the two "designated" boys and $B_3$ as one of the extra students is equivalent to choosing $\{B_1, B_3\}$ as the designated boys and $B_2$ as the extra student. The second method, whose three terms correspond to the mutually exclusive cases of choosing 2 boys and 4 girls, 3 boys and 3 girls, and 4 boys and 2 girls, never double-counts.